# Поиск в массиве наиболее приближенного значения

Tags: php

Добрый день, вскипел мозг, у нас не получается...

Есть массив:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => AD
            [latitude] => 42.5
            [longitude] => 1.5166666666667
            [tz] => Europe/Andorra
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => AE
            [latitude] => 25.3
            [longitude] => 55.3
            [tz] => Asia/Dubai
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => AF
            [latitude] => 34.516666666667
            [longitude] => 69.2
            [tz] => Asia/Kabul
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [code] => AG
            [latitude] => 17.05
            [longitude] => -61.8
            [tz] => America/Antigua
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [code] => AI
            [latitude] => 18.2
            [longitude] => -63.066666666667
            [tz] => America/Anguilla
        )
```

...

```
 [413] => Array
        (
            [code] => ZM
            [latitude] => -15.416666666667
            [longitude] => 28.283333333333
            [tz] => Africa/Lusaka
        )

    [414] => Array
        (
            [code] => ZW
            [latitude] => -17.833333333333
            [longitude] => 31.05
            [tz] => Africa/Harare
        )

    )
```

требуется выбрать 1 массив(индекс) у которого наиболее приближены latitude и longitude к заданному значению(к примеру):
Latitude:-66.0000000
Longitude:92.0000000

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Что вы делаете? Приведите неработающий код или вашу идею алгоритма, которую вы не можете реализовать. В чём вообще может быть проблема пройтись по масиву циклом и найти минимальное расстояние?

Comment: Приходит значение долготы и широты москвы(к примеру) надо из массива выбрать наиболее приближенное значение к широте и долготе москвы чтобы узнать time zone. Time zone это [tz] => Africa/Harare (к примеру). Сервисы не предлагать.

Comment: Ну так а сделали вы уже что? Покажите нам ваши попытки решения данной задачи. А мы вам поможем поправить ваш алгоритм.

Comment: длины отрезка между координатами посчитайте, найдите наименьшую

Comment: @morfei, поскольку речь о TZ, искать надо минимальное удаление **по долготе**.

Бывает, в разных странах (широтах) даже одна и таже долгота относится к разным часовым поясам (TZ), но в Вашей базе похоже таких данных нет.

(А среднеквадратичное отклонение оставьте ракетчикам...)

Comment: http://mapguide.osgeo.org/about.html вот это может вам поможет, ну и вообще сам http://osgeo.org

Comment: Благодарю, но веб сервисы не нужны, к примеру http://www.geonames.org/ справился бы с моей задачей, но мне нужно решение без использования сервисов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) вам в помощь.

В качестве критерия проверки - длина отрезка по теореме пифагора.
sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2)+pow((y2-y1),2));

Задаете изначальный минимум, который вас устроит в качестве критерия близости (пешком ~3км), и индекс(-1) потом сравниваете. Если расстояние(см выше) меньше, задаете новый минимум и новый индекс.

На выходе - нужный индекс первого совпадения и расстояние.
Сложность О(N).

Чтобы найти все ближайшие точки, используйте алгоритм выше, но значения записывайте в массив индекс-расстояние. Потом отсортируйте и выведите нужные N значений или нужные значения не более данного.

Comment: в последнем абзаце перебор со сложностью, лучше искать в квадрате а не в радиусе, для этого надо всего-лишь взять координаты квадрата описывающего круг с радиусом поиска и использовать их как граничные (это всё чтобы не вычислять отрезок каждый раз)

Comment: Квадрат дает разброс почти в 1,5 раза. Во многих случаях это может быть критичным. Хотя для города подобный алгоритм вообще неприемлем: можно быть в 1 метре от цели... которая за пятикилометровым забором предприятия.

Comment: А  для достаточно удаленных координат теорема пифагора не работает (градус долготы имеет разную длину (в километрах) на разных широтах).

Comment: Вместо наименьшего корня из суммы квадратов эффективнее искать наименьшую саму сумму квадратов. Но как правильно сказал @avp, это всё равно математически не вполне верно.

Comment: @morfei: Что куда выводит единицы? Какие значения величины `$raznmt` получаются? Это они у вас все равны 1?

Comment: вообщем я разобрался, работает но... как я понимаю она находит наиболее приближенную точку lat+lon="значение" и чем это значение приближено к 0 тем оно ближе, ГЛАВНОЕ ТО ЧТО ОНА НАХОДИТ ВСЕ ЖЕ НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ. Нужна формула которая рассчитывало бы приближенное значение к Latitude и Longitude где Latitude(вроде не Longitude) наиболее первостепенно. 
К примеру есть точка 54.318188,55.446422 надо найти куда она приближение и находит она 50.191184,53.205226(приближенностьПо форм. 6,35) хотя фактический приближение она к 60.59734,56.837982(приближенность по текущей формуле 7,67). Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Для нахождения наименьшего расстояния между двумя точками, зная из широту и долготу, нужно использовать [формулу](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

```
d = r * arccos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1)).
```

Тут `r` -- радиус планеты, (`lat1`, `lon1`) -- широта и долгота первой точки, (`lat2`, `lon2`) -- второй. Поскольку `r` у нас (эммммм... приблизительно) константа, её можно не учитывать при поиске. Поскольку arccos -- монотонно убывающая функция, достаточно искать *максимум* величины

```
sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1)
```

(Разумеется, `sin(lat1)` и `cos(lat1)` можно вычислить заранее для ускорения процесса.)

Comment: @morfei: читайте внимательно ответ, вам надо искать не минимум, а максимум же. И не забудьте поправить начальное значение `$raznmtst`.

Comment: @morfei: что значит "не то выводит"? что оно выводит, и что вы ожидаете?

Comment: как понимаю оно возражает расстояние между точками? 

выводит вот такое:

0.14794266984722
1.865279417498
1.4762773587469
0.28426965847091
1.081892058941
1.0793133580269
2.1394052263827
0.8971425501648
1.002346974197
0.33216959382339
2.9730119509917
0.29162707134854
3.0156398027537

Comment: Нет, не расстояние, смотрите формулу в ответе. Приведите код, непонятно, что кто куда выводит и что чему не соответствует.

Comment: код:
<?
$z = 0;
$a = sizeof($tz_date);

$raznmtst = '-1000';
while ($a > $z) {
    $raznmt = acos(sin((double) $tz_date[$z]['latitude']) * sin((double) $Latitude) + cos((double) $tz_date[$z]['latitude']) * cos((double) $Latitude) * cos($Longitude - $tz_date[$z]['longitude'])) ;
    if ($raznmt > $raznmtst) {
        $raznmtst = $raznmt;
        
        $z2 = $z;
    }
    $z++;
}
?>

Comment: @morfei: смотрите внимательно формулу, арккосинус не нужен.

Comment: уже побывал но все равно не тот результат. Как будто упускаю что то элементарное. Так да, это и есть самое наибольшее значение среди всех имеющихся, но увы истинный ответ не тот.

Comment: @morfei: (1) А может, вы ищете не то? Вы ищете ближайшую точку к точкам массива, а вам по факту надо что-то другое? (2) Находится ли данная точка ближе всего найденной из массива, или нет? Проверьте по карте. (3) Попробуйте взять тестовую точку, близкую к точке из массива. (4) А не в градусах ли ваши углы? Проверьте, не надо ли перевести их в радианы.

Comment: @morfei: да, точно, в массиве углы в градусах :)

Comment: и так: У меня есть долгота и широта formatted_address:Ufa, Republic of Bashkortostan, Russia
Latitude:54.8098660
Longitude:56.0939110 и есть массив в котором хранятся часовые пояса. Следовательно нам надо найти ту долготу и широту которая наиболее приближена к заданному значению чтобы определить часовой пояс.

Comment: code
$z  = 0;
$a = sizeof($tz_date);
$Latitude = '54.8098660';
$Longitude = '56.0939110';
$raznmtst = '-1000';
while ($a > $z) {
$raznmt = sin((double)$Latitude) * sin((double)$tz_date[$z]['latitude']) + cos((double)$Latitude) * cos((double)$tz_date[$z]['latitude']) * cos($tz_date[$z]['longitude'] - $Longitude);



if($raznmt>$raznmtst)
{  

 $raznmtst = $raznmt;
 
 $z2 = $z;
}
  $z++;
}
code

Comment: @morfei: ну, перевод в радианы у вас где? Нету.

Answer (score 0):

Никто код за вас писать не будет. Не то место. Но с идее поможем.

Воспользуйтесь среднеквадратичным отклонением: посчитайте его, и для широты, и для долготы, по каждой позиции и возьмите ту, у которой они наиболее маленькие по сравнению с заданным.

Статья в ВИКИ: [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Среднеквадратичное_отклонение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)